# How to make a MAtLab GUI to visualise polarisation ellipse

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have made some `.m files` to compute the Stokes Polarisation Parameters. There are two scrpits:`polarisationFromLight` which accepts three parameters and returns the polarisation ellipse along with the stokes parameters and `polarisationFromStokes` which accepts the stokes parameters and draws the polarisation ellipse.

My files are

**polarisationFromLight.m**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                        %
%                                                        %
%  polarisationFromLight.m                               %
%  Matlab Script that gets the x/y component             %
%  and phase end returns the polarisation ellipse        %
%  and the 4 stokes parameters                           %
%                                                        %
%  Author:Thanos Stamatopoulos                           %
%  Date:March 2013                                       %
%                                                        %
%  Neeeds calculateEllipse.m                             %
%         angle.m                                        %
%         deg2rad.m                                      %
%                                                        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Eox=input('Give me the x amplitude of the wave: ');
Eoy=input('Now give the y amplitude of the wave: ');
phiDeg=input('Finally give the relative phase in degrees between x and y component: ');

if (phiDeg==(90)|phiDeg==-90 && Eox==Eoy)
    angle(90)
else
    %semiminor axis b
    phiRad=deg2rad(phiDeg);
    alpha=Eoy/Eox;
    x=asin(sin(2*alpha)*sin(phiRad))/2;
    beta=tan(x);

    %inclination angle-ellipse's orientation
    psi=atand((2*Eox*Eoy*cosd(phiDeg))/(Eox^2-Eoy^2))/2;

    %draw the ellipse
    p = calculateEllipse(0, 0, 1, beta, psi, 1000);
    plot(p(:,1), p(:,2), '.'),axis equal
end

%calculate the normalised Stokes parameters
I=Eox^2+Eoy^2;
Q=Eox^2-Eoy^2;
U=2*Eox*Eoy*cosd(phiDeg);
V=2*Eox*Eoy*sind(phiDeg);

%plot them on the canvas
text(1.01,.5,['\fontsize{16}\color{red}I= ' num2str(I/I)])
text(1.01,0.4,['\fontsize{16}\color{red}Q= ' num2str(Q/I)])
text(1.01,0.3,['\fontsize{16}\color{red}U= ' num2str(U/I)])
text(1.01,0.2,['\fontsize{16}\color{red}V= ' num2str(V/I)])

%Don't forget the left/hand polarisation
if (V>0)
    text(1.01,.8,['\fontsize{16}\color[rgb]{0 .5 0}Right Handed' ])
elseif(V<0)
    text(1.01,.8,['\fontsize{16}\color[rgb]{0 .5 0}Left Handed' ])
end
```

**polarisationFromStokes.m**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                        %
%                                                        %
%  polarisationFromStokes.m                              %
%  Matlab Script that gets the 4 stokes parameters       %
%  end returns the polarisation ellipse                  %
%                                                        %
%  Author:Thanos Stamatopoulos                           %
%  Date:March 2013                                       %
%                                                        %
%  Neeeds calculateEllipse.m                             %
%         angle.m                                        %
%         rad2deg.m                                      %
%                                                        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I=input('Give me the I stokes parameter: ');
Q=input('Give me the Q stokes parameter: ');
U=input('Give me the U stokes parameter: ');
V=input('Give me the V stokes parameter: ');

if (V==(1)|V==-1)
    angle(90)
elseif(Q<0)
    %semiminor axis b
    x=asin(V/I)/2;
    beta=tan(x);
    p = calculateEllipse(0, 0, 1, beta, 90, 1000);
    plot(p(:,1), p(:,2), '.'),axis equal
else
    %semiminor axis b
    x=asin(V/I)/2;
    beta=tan(x);

    %inclination angle-ellipse's orientation
    psi=atan(U/Q)/2;
    psiDeg=rad2deg(psi);

    %draw the ellipse
    p = calculateEllipse(0, 0, 1, beta, psiDeg, 1000);
    plot(p(:,1), p(:,2), '.')
    axis equal
    grid on

end

if (V>0)
    text(1.01,.7,['\fontsize{16}\color[rgb]{0 .5 0}Right Handed' ])
elseif(V<0)
    text(1.01,.7,['\fontsize{16}\color[rgb]{0 .5 0}Left Handed' ])
end

text(1.01,.5,['\fontsize{16}\color{red}I= ' num2str(I/I)])
text(1.01,0.4,['\fontsize{16}\color{red}Q= ' num2str(Q/I)])
text(1.01,0.3,['\fontsize{16}\color{red}U= ' num2str(U/I)])
text(1.01,0.2,['\fontsize{16}\color{red}V= ' num2str(V/I)])
```

**function `angle`**

```
    function angle=angle(phi)
    t=[0:1:360];
    x=sind(t);
    y=sind(t-phi);
    scatter(x,y,'.')
    axis equal
    grid on

**function calculateellipse**

function [X Y] = calculateEllipse(x, y, a, b, angle, steps)
    %# This functions returns points to draw an ellipse
    %#
    %#  @param x     X coordinate
    %#  @param y     Y coordinate
    %#  @param a     Semimajor axis
    %#  @param b     Semiminor axis
    %#  @param angle Angle of the ellipse (in degrees)
    %#

    error(nargchk(5, 6, nargin));
    if nargin<6, steps = 36; end

    beta = -angle * (pi / 180);
    sinbeta = sin(beta);
    cosbeta = cos(beta);

    alpha = linspace(0, 360, steps)' .* (pi / 180);
    sinalpha = sin(alpha);
    cosalpha = cos(alpha);

    X = x + (a * cosalpha * cosbeta - b * sinalpha * sinbeta);
    Y = y + (a * cosalpha * sinbeta + b * sinalpha * cosbeta);

    if nargout==1, X = [X Y]; end
end
```

**rad2deg**

```
function deg2rad = deg2rad(degrees)

% RADIANS (DEGREES)
%
% Convert Radians to Degrees.
% Athanasios Stamatopoulos
%

deg2rad = (pi/180)*degrees;
```

**deg2rad**

```
function rad2deg = rad2deg(radians)

%
% Convert Radians to Degrees.
% Athanasios Stamatopoulos 2010
%

rad2deg = radians/(pi/180);
```

Is it possible to make a GUI where the user will have to type each parameter, so as to get the polarisation ellipse plotted.

---

**EDIT**

So far I designed the GUI

[image]

The `.m file` generated from this is

```
function varargout = Stokes2Ellipse(varargin)
% STOKES2ELLIPSE M-file for Stokes2Ellipse.fig
%      STOKES2ELLIPSE, by itself, creates a new STOKES2ELLIPSE or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = STOKES2ELLIPSE returns the handle to a new STOKES2ELLIPSE or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      STOKES2ELLIPSE('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in STOKES2ELLIPSE.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      STOKES2ELLIPSE('Property','Value',...) creates a new STOKES2ELLIPSE or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before Stokes2Ellipse_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to Stokes2Ellipse_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help Stokes2Ellipse

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 12-Mar-2013 09:20:33

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @Stokes2Ellipse_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @Stokes2Ellipse_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before Stokes2Ellipse is made visible.
function Stokes2Ellipse_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to Stokes2Ellipse (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for Stokes2Ellipse
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes Stokes2Ellipse wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = Stokes2Ellipse_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;



function Itext_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Itext (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of Itext as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of Itext as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function Itext_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Itext (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function Qtext_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Qtext (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of Qtext as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of Qtext as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function Qtext_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Qtext (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function Utext_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Utext (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of Utext as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of Utext as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function Utext_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Utext (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function Vtext_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Vtext (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of Vtext as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of Vtext as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function Vtext_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Vtext (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

Comment: What part of building this into a GUI are you struggling with? Have you read the relevant Matlab documentation? Which part is confusing you? As it stands, youre asking us to just summarize the Matlab help sections and post them here. That's not the purpose of this forum.

Comment: @jerad: Thank you very much for your comment! I know how to design it using `GUIDE` but I don't know how to make it happen. What I mean is, that I don't know how to make the GUI get the values and plot the ellipse... I will add to my question the gui's `.m` file and a screenshot of it...

Comment: Read the inline comments and hints in the generated m-file. You just need to extract the entries from the text (look in the text callbacks) and get your function to plot on the correct axes (give it a handle to your created axes).

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the Matlab documentation about [Coding UI behavior](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/code-to-run-the-gui.html). I guess it would help you with most of the issues here.